# Trying to send csv as an email attachment in C#

Tags: c#, email-attachments, streamwriter, memorystream, system.net.mail

When I use `StreamWriter.WriteLine` it doesn't seem to write anything to a `MemoryStream`.

-"data" is something that is previously populated. It is an object[] that includes objects that have Name, Date, and PhoneNumber.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
CustomerReport[] customers = (CustomerReport[])data;
foreach (var d in customers)
{
    sw.WriteLine($"{d.Name},{d.Date},{d.PhoneNumber}");
}
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(sw.BaseStream, "CustomerReport.csv", "text/csv");
```

However the `csv` attachment is always an empty `csv`.

Update:
I got it figured out. It was actually the `MemoryStream()`.
I just set my `MemoryStream()` which in this case is `sw.BaseStream.Postion = 0`

Below is a working version:

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(new MemoryStream());
CustomerReport[] customers = (CustomerReport[])data;
foreach (var d in customers)
{
    sw.WriteLine($"{d.Name},{d.Date},{d.PhoneNumber}");
    sw.Flush();
}
sw.BaseStream.Position = 0;
Attachment attachment = new Attachment(sw.BaseStream, "CustomerReport.csv", "text/csv");
```

Comment: I checked the StreamWriter sw and it does have the characters in the char buffer that I want to write. However, nothing is written to the BaseStream.

Comment: Likely a typo in the question, but there's an extra closing brace at the end of WriteLine() call, meaning code further down might not be part of the block or scope you think it is.

Comment: Thank you. I typed the code in the question. I didn't copy and paste. I have corrected this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling [`Flush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.flush(v=vs.110).aspx) method after `foreach`:

```
sw.Flush();
```

Comment: That didn't work. I checked the StreamWriter sw and it does have the characters in the char buffer that I want to write. However, nothing is written to the BaseStream.

Comment: @clueless7788 can you try setting AutoFlush to true: `sw.AutoFlush = true;` before foreach

Comment: I tried `sw.AutoFlush = true;` and it worked. `sw.BaseStream` buffer has data in it but my attachment is still empty.